# Mysql select from multiple tables and a new table is created every month

Tags: php, mysql, asterisk

I have at this moment 3 tables: cdr, cdr_201502 and cdr_201503, next month the system will create a new one cdr_201504 and so on. I'm doing an php page to select from database some information and i need a select from all tables and i need automate this thing, i can use union select or inner join but every month i need to write a new union select for the newly created table... table have the same columns. please help i already have google'd all pages but cant find any related to my need.

I cant put all code here  but i can give an example:

```
select * from cdr where src='470' and calltype like '%' 
and billable>'-1'  and datetime>'2015-01-01 00:00:00' and datetime 
<'2015-  03-30     23:59:59' order by datetime desc
union all
select * from cdr_201502 where src='470' and calltype like '%' 
and billable>'-1'  and datetime>'2015-01-01 00:00:00' and datetime 
<'2015-  03-30     23:59:59' order by datetime desc
union all 
select * from cdr_201503 where src='470' and calltype like '%' 
and billable>'-1'  and datetime>'2015-01-01 00:00:00' and datetime 
<'2015-  03-30     23:59:59' order by datetime desc;
```

next month i will be needed to add a new union so how to automate this?

**Question:** can I use a query to select tables from *information_schema*
 and then to use select, or to make an trigger to update tables(but again I will need to change trigger every month)?

Comment: "a new table is created every month" - why? This is probably a very silly design decision and is most likely the problem which needs to be fixed here. I for one would consider it a courtesy to provide an explanation for such an unusual constraint.

Comment: i dont know why, but system is doing every month one table... thats bad but thats the situation...i submited an tiket to suport i still waiting an answer , think they will say that this way is better (this is an PBX system and we dont have possibility to influence them)

Answer (score 0):

**Part 1 : can I use a query to select tables from information_schema and then to use select**

We may use query to take the table names from information_schema

```
 SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
 WHERE table_type = 'BASE TABLE'
 AND table_schema = 'database-name'
 AND table_name like 'cdr%';
```

We may also create the query little dynamic if we follow a pattern in the table name creation, we can take the table name in a variable like $cdr based on date time stamp and use it in our query incrementing the value of $cdr in a loop

```
select * from '".$cdr." ' where src='470' and calltype like '%'
```

**Part 2 : Select columns from multiple tables having same structure**

**Using UNION**

```
(select * from cdr where src='470' and calltype like '%' )
UNION 
(select * from cdr_201502 where src='470' and calltype like '%' );
```

**Using ALIAS**

```
SELECT cdr.id, cdr.name, cdr_201502.id 
FROM cdr
  INNER JOIN cdr_201502 on cdr.id = cdr_201502.id
```

Comment: SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables
     WHERE  table_name like 'cdr%';  

this is enought to get table name

about the variable im not sure i understand how to do that ((
  ; i think mysql dont permit to use FROM Multiple Tables, its posible for one table only

Comment: `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like 'cdr%';` will have performance issue, if you have multiple databases, as it will search the table from all databases.

Comment: hmmm, ok agree about performance... and no, i dont have multible databases, only one.

Comment: If you have only on db. In that case  `SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables WHERE table_name like 'cdr%';` will do the job

Comment: ok that resolved, next how to use table name from this query to do another query and select some information from all tables, and why there is not possible to use SELECT * FROM cdr, cdr_201503 where statement; if tables have the same structure...

Comment: you can do it using `UNION` Or `ALIAS`. Check answer in part 2 of your question

Comment: Note, all described variants will not work on really large tables. Query have be much more date-specific to do it effective way. Correct solution - do select only by indexed column and construct script which will write query for you.

Comment: thanks, now i need to figure out how to make this script to work, to get data from information schema and put it into an array, and to make an if statement, but not sure if that will work lol, i'm a little skeptic about this method will try if there isn't other way to do that...